# Can I use a single 3-conductor cable to rewire a switch in the US?

Tags: wiring

In replacing old knob and tube wiring to a light switch, is there any safety or code reason (United States) to not use a single 3-conductor cable for the two hot wires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a single *cable* with three *conductors* (like a single run of 14/3) is the most common way to wire a switch and is certainly the right way to do it.

If using US-colored wire, 14/3 has black, red, and white.  White carries the neutral to the switch (which is required now), and the red and black are used for the switched hot.  And then of course there is the omnipresent bare ground wire.

Comment: Thanks! It seemed like the logical way to do. I've edited the q to reflect the correct terms.

Comment: @PhilEsra Are you in the US?  We get global questions here, so for wiring questions like this (and most other questions), state your location.

Comment: Yes, when we say "3-conductor cable" (14/3) we actually mean cable with FOUR wires: Red, Black, White and Bare.